# AutoML Vision Training gives "Job reached state FAILURE"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision, google-cloud-automl

I am using google autoML Vision's Image classification to train a dataset of 230 categories having a total of 90,000 images. I started its training for 10 node-hours. But after 10 hours it returned with the error message "Job reached state FAILURE". I even checked operation progress using the curl request which just returns:

```
{
 "progressPercent": 100
 "done": true,
 "error": {
     "code": 13,
     "message": "Job reached state FAILURE"
 }
}
```

Is there any way to find out what was the actual reason behind the failure?